# Automate populating fields in rails from one link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So i'm working on some links. Basically i have a list of events, They have one link inside that looks like this,

```
Provider1.co.uk/event/1F004CC6C1FA8142
```

Not much to go on i know, However if this is called to provider 1's api, i can access the date, venue name, the location, etc.

Now i haven't set this up yet, However i'm wanting a JS script to load the api. (which i have elsewhere).

Now to sidetrack a little heres provider twos link.

```
provider2.com/buy-(name-of-event)-tickets/(venue-name)-tickets/(Date-of-event)/perf/1028576
```

And provider 3's

```
provider3.com/(event-name)-tickets-(event-name)-(Location-Name)-(venue-Name)-(Date-of-event)/event/9277843/
```

Now how it stands at the moment is we enter these into text boxes manually.

We'd like to look at making it automatic, The provider1 is automated. Basically we want the other 2 providers to be automatically filled into the inputboxes on page load. Thats it, Sounds simple but i'm not 100% sure it is :)

Sam

Heres the json response from provider one by the way

```
"venue": {
        "venueId": 10191,
        "name": "Venue Name",
        "street": "Location Street",
        "city": "Location Name",
       }
 "eventId": 2176597,
      "status": "onSale",
      "name": "Event Name",
      "eventDate": "2016-06-22 17:00:00"
```

I'm using rails, It might be easier if i can make the api call in rails rather than javascript.

So i'm currently using HTTParty,

```
response = HTTParty.get('url')
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

I have called the json with byebug, And it throws everything back i need, However if i put `json.eventId` It doesnt work?

Heres the response

```
{"details"=>{"totalResults"=>1, "totalPages"=>1, "currentPage"=>1, "resultsPerPage"=>50}, "results"=>[{"eventId"=>2176597}]}
```

However the eventId is apparently Null

Comment: You have some link that you want to parse into a form?

Comment: Kinda, Currently in the process of getting httparty to work, basicallyprovider 1 can have an api call to get all the information about the event. From this response i want to populate everything inside the brackets. I'm thinking i could just place it in as a `<%=%>` from the api call. I just cant get it to work at the moment, Will add an edit where i am at the moment

Comment: @Marwen Added Edit ^_^